# Passing reference_wrapper objects as function arguments in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

How does one pass and operate on constant (or non constant) references inside STL containers. Say I have a function:

```
bool foo(const Obj& A, const Obj& B) {
  // do some computation on A & B
}
```

and since A & B always occur together, I would like to put them in an STL pair:

```
bool foo(const  std::pair<Obj, Obj>& A_and_B) {
  // do some computation on A & B
}
```

However now both objects A & B get copied into a pair every time foo needs to be called. Looking around I found reference_wrapper in C++11. Though doing something like this doesn't quite work:

```
bool foo(const  std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<Obj>, std::reference_wrapper<Obj>>& A_and_B) {
  // do some computation on A & B
}

bool foo(const  std::pair<Obj, Obj>& A_and_B) {
  foo(std::make_pair(std::ref(A_and_B.first), std::ref(A_and_B.second)));
}
```

What is the correct way of passing containers with reference values without using pointers?

Comment: There is no "the" correct way, but one option for you is to make the formal argument type `pair<Obj const&, Obj const&> const&`, or just `pair<Obj const&, Obj const&> const`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid copy when make_pair, why not define the pair as `std::pair<Obj&, Obj&>` directly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
class Obj 
{
};

bool foo(const  std::pair<Obj, Obj>& A_and_B) {
  // do some computation on A & B
    std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;
}

bool foo(const  std::pair<Obj&, Obj&>& A_and_B) {
  // do some computation on A & B
    std::cout << "ref version foo" << std::endl;
}

int main( void )
{
    Obj A;
    Obj B;
    foo( std::make_pair(std::ref(A), std::ref(B)) );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'd want to remove the first overload and change the references to reference to `const` in the second.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, passing just a pair of references (no copying):

```
#include <utility>          // pair
#include <functional>       // ref
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Obj {};

auto foo( pair<Obj const&, Obj const&> const ab )
{
    Obj const& a = ab.first;
    Obj const& b = ab.second;
    cout << &a << " " << &b << endl;
}

auto main() -> int
{
    Obj a;
    Obj b;
    cout << &a << " " << &b << endl;
    foo( make_pair( ref( a ), ref( b ) ) );
}
```

This works nicely because `std::make_pair` has special support for `std::reference_wrapper` arguments, then deducing reference to the referred to type.

`std::reference_wrapper` is the result type of `std::ref`.

Comment: I like this, I think it's the cleanest suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Since `std::make_pair` supports move semantics, you just need to write your function as you suggested, but when calling it *move* objects `A` and `B` into the `std::make_pair` as shown below:

```
// Just as you already suggested
bool foo(const  std::pair<Obj, Obj>& A_and_B) {
  // do some computation on A & B
}
```

Call it as:

```
int main( void )
{
    Obj A; // work on A
    Obj B; // work on B
    auto A_and_B = std::make_pair(std::move(A), std::move(B)); // effectively moves A and B; no copies!
    // A and B are now reset, but you can use A_and_B.first and A_and_B.second!
    foo( A_and_B  ); 
    return 0;
}
```

[Live demo.](http://ideone.com/vaAPwn)

Comment: It seems *very* unlikely the OP wants to move the argument objects.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It seems everyone is confused and using `reference_wrapper` is a good evidence of it. I believe the OP wants to tie `A` and `B` together without making unnecessary copies.

Comment: I agree with that comment, modulo s/everyone/everyone else/g. But moving isn't the answer, because moving (1) for movable types changes the actual arguments, which is undesirable, and (2) for non-movable types reduces to copying, which also is generally undesirable. Passing a pair of references does the job nicely. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Since you are passing the pair by reference, it is not copied. However, `Obj A=A_and_B.first` will create a copy. If you want to avoid that, you can get a reference to the element, i.e.

`Obj &A=A_and_B.first`.

Comment: I don't mind the downvote, but I'm curious as to what I got wrong in my answer..?